# What's the right way to test rails controllers in isolation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, controller

Even a seemingly simple index action feels incredibly complicated to test in isolation.
I find myself having to mock out several of my `User` and `Tenant` methods just to get through the `before_filter`s. Then I need to mock out `Kaminari` and `Tenant#users` for the action.

This feels excessive for testing a controller action with no control flow.

TDD principle would say that an excessive need for mocking is a sign of poor design, but then I'm not sure how I would extract this functionality into a domain object.

Is this sort of painful mocking standard for testing Rails controllers? Is there better way to do this that I'm simply not aware of?

For instance, perhaps skipping `before_filter`s would make this less painful, but as they are consequential private methods, I feel that skipping them is missing the point.

```
  class UsersController < AdminController
    before_filter :check_auth
    before_filter :check_admin
    around_filter :set_tenant_time_zone, if: current_tenant

    def index
      Kaminari.paginate(current_tenant.users).page(params[:page])
    end

    private

    def current_user
      # gets user from session
    end

    def current_tenant
      current_user.tenant if current_user
    end

    def set_tenant_time_zone
      Time.use_zone(current_tenant.time_zone, &block)
    end

    def check_auth
      redirect_to login_url unless AuthChecker.new(current_user, request.remote_ip).has_access?
    end

    def check_admin
      redirect_to root_url unless current_user.is_admin?
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do all those mocks/stubs if you want to run those before_filters but I think, that, for those cases, is better to use some spec helper method to create a logged in user so, on your spec, you only need to call that method on a "before(:each)" block of your controller where you want a user.

In spec_helper.rb:

```
def current_user(stubs = {})
  unless @current_user
    u = FactoryGirl.build(:user, stubs)
    u.save(:validate => false)
    @current_user = u
  end
  @current_user
end

def current_user_session(stubs = {}, user_stubs = {})
  @current_session ||= mock_model("Session", {:record => nil, :user => current_user(user_stubs)}.merge(stubs))
end

def login(session_stubs = {}, user_stubs = {})
  UserSession.stub(:find).and_return(current_user_session(session_stubs, user_stubs))
  controller.stub(:current_user => @current_user)
end
```

so, on the controller specs that require a logged in user with some special stub I can do

```
describe 'GET index' do
  before(:each) do
    login #this does all you need to pass the filters
  end

  it 'does something' do
    current_user.stub(:some_method)
    get :index
    expect(response).to something
  end
end
```

that way the test only has stubs, instances and expectations for the actual code of the action and not the filters

Comment: Thanks for your input. I was hoping for a solution that could help me simplify my mocks while still testing in absolute isolation but perhaps that's just wishful thinking. It does seem like controllers are just inherently difficult to test in isolation.